# Creating and merging layers in Resnet

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, resnet

I am working on image dataset

I first resized all images

```
im_size1 = 128
im_size2 = 128
i = 0 
for f, breed in tqdm(df_train.values):
    if type(cv2.imread('train/{}.jpeg'.format(f)))==type(None):
        continue
    else:
        img = cv2.imread('train/{}.jpeg'.format(f))
        label = one_hot_labels[i]
        x_train.append(cv2.resize(img, (im_size1, imt_size2)))
        y_train.append(label)
        i += 1
np.save('x_train2',x_train)
np.save('y_train2',y_train)
print('Done')
```

On the second run i passed Histogram of Gradient Feature
Note: Model was same in both cases. Ran on different projects, got different results

```
i = 0 
for f, breed in tqdm(df_train.values):
    if type(cv2.imread('train/{}.jpeg'.format(f)))==type(None):
        continue
    else:
        img = cv2.imread('train/{}.jpeg'.format(f))
        label = one_hot_labels[i]
        resizedImage = cv2.resize(img, (im_size1, im_size2))
        hog_vec, hog_vis = feature.hog(resizedImage, visualize=True)
        resizedImageVec = cv2.resize(hog_vec, (im_size1, im_size2))
        x_train.append(resizedImageVec)
        #np.concatenate(x_train, hog_vec[:])

        y_train.append(label)
        i += 1
np.save('x_train2hog',x_train)
np.save('y_train2hog',y_train)
print('Done')
```

Then configured the model like so

```
base_model = ResNet50(weights = None, include_top=False, input_shape=(im_size1, im_size2, 3))

# Add a new top layer
x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)

# This is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# First: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
#for layer in base_model.layers:
#    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

callbacks_list = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', verbose=1)]
model.summary()
```

Now my professor has asked me this.

"Train last layer using images, then train last layer using features (different representation of images). Concatenate these two layers, and then train one more layer."

Please guide me how can i accomplish this

Comment: The question can be improved and simplified. For example, what you are asking about is not specific to ResNet

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Merge layers from Keras API](https://keras.io/layers/merge/)

`keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)`

and the functional version:

`keras.layers.concatenate(inputs, axis=-1)`